# Should I delete my answers?

Tags: discussion, answers

Should I delete my answers if they have a score of 0 and are not accepted? As I feel that just clutter the page a little and they aren't helping anyone.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no shame in an answer receiving no upvotes or not being accepted. Be patient. Do not be discouraged if an answer is not (yet) accepted or has received no upvotes. I have had answers accepted or upvoted months or years after posting them. I had an upvote to a zero-votes answer which I had posted four years before.

Take the long view. Remember that you are not just answering the question for the original poster. Someone might be guided to your answers in the future via a search engine such as Google, and feel inclined to upvote. This is a key part of what Stack Exchange does.

In any event, you should be providing answers to help both the OP and others, not to get votes or points. Upvotes are a very crude way of measuring an answer's utility. I have myself been embarrassed by answers of mine which got plenty of votes, but which I felt were not as good as other answers to the same question, and I have deleted them.

Provided you are sure that an answer you have provided is a good one, that you have researched the question carefully, and not just posted an 'I think' answer straight from the hip, and (especially) provided links to reference material such as dictionary definitions or reliable usage or grammar guidance, leave it alone.

If an answer of yours gets downvoted, consider very carefully why this might be so. Study answers that have been upvoted and try to work out why.